# {{ user }} not working in my template in Django

Tags: django

Here is my template :

```
{% load static %}

<div class="header clearfix">
    <nav>
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-fill float-right ">
            {% for button in buttons %}
                    {{ user.id }}
                    {{ request.user.id }}
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

And here is my template tag :

```
from django import template
from menu.models import Button

register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('menu/home.html', takes_context=True)
def show_menu(context):
    request = context.get('request')
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        buttons = Button.objects.filter(button_noco = False)
        return {'buttons': buttons}
```

In my template tag, `request.user.is_authenticated` is working fine.  The problem is that in my template, I can't display `user.id`, `request.user.id` or anything like to the user (like `request.user.is_authenticated` for example).

Why?

Comment: You are returning just the buttons object, return request as well: `{'buttons': buttons, 'request': request}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('menu/home.html', takes_context=True)
def show_menu(context):
    request = context.get('request')
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        buttons = Button.objects.filter(button_noco = False)
        return {'buttons': buttons, 'request': request <<<<----}
```

Answer (score 0):

What information do you want to display?

The id of user in 'request',or, the id of button in database?
try this:

```
{% for button in buttons %}
          {{ button.id }}
{% endfor %}
```